# Factorise $x^{17}-x$

Tags: factoring

Lets say I have an expression: $$x^{17}-x$$
I have to factorise it.
What I did:
Removed common $x$ outside the expression:$$x(x^{16}-1)$$
What I observed is $x^{16}-1$ can be written as $(x^4)^2-1^2$. So applying the identity of difference of squares $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, I got the answer as $$x(x^4+1)(x^4-1)$$
The last term is a perfect square too. So I again factorised it: $x(x^4+1)(x^2+1)(x^2-1)$
Then Again: $$x(x^4+1)(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1)$$

But when I used wolfram - alpha to check, I got

$$x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)(x^8+1)$$

Where did I go wrong?
Also, can we write that

1. $x^4-1$
2. $x^2-1$
   Are the roots of $x^{17}-x$?
   Ideally, if wolfram - alpha gave the result as $(x^8+1)$, so $(x^8-1)$ is also a root if $x^{17}+x$.

Comment: You made a mistake:  $x^{16}-1=(x^8+1)(x^8-1)$.  You used the law of exponents incorrectly:  $(x^4)^2=x^8$, not $x^{16}$.

Comment: I don't understand one thing: When I google $x^{4}^{2}$, It shows $x^{16}$, But when I put: $(x^4)^2$, I get $x^8$. Is it that it is first calculating $4^2$ in the first equation?

Comment: $(x^4)^2$ is very different from $x^{(4^2)}$.  Google is likely interpreting the latter, when you mean the former.

Comment: Thank you for your time! @Randall

Comment: Yes, unlike other operations, if you doing put explicit parentheses $a^{b^c}$ is evaluated as $a^{(b^c)}.$ This is the custom because $(a^b)^c$ has a simpler formula, a^{bc}.$

Comment: I will just note that with complex numbers, you can write $$x^{17}-x = x\prod_{k=0}^{15} (x-\exp(\pi i k/8)).$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is in the third equation. In particular you should have: $$x^{16} - 1=(x^8+1)(x^8 - 1)$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. so can we say that $(x^8-1)$ can be $((x^4)^2-1^2)$

Comment: Yes, which then gives you $x^8 - 1 = (x^4 + 1)(x^4 - 1)$. Can you see how to continue by factoring $x^4 - 1$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: (+1) If you allow complex numbers then you can also factorise $x^4+1$